# SFTP transfer a file from server to desktop

Tags: ssh, database, sftp

I am trying to compete an assignment for school and I have one final step. I have use the "put" command to load the file. Then ran a spool and the file followed by ending the spool. Now I am back at the SFTP and I use the "get" command which I am thinking worked by this display that was outputted:

```
sftp> get spool01.1st
Fetching /class/cm320a/12/spool01.1st to spool01.1st
/class/cm320a/12/spool01.1st         100%  136  0.1KB/s  00:00
```

But now I need to attach the database that was created only I can't find the file on my computer to use. If I understand things correctly then the spooled filed was sent to `/class/cm320a/12/spool01.1st` – how would I go about getting it to my laptop so I can submit it for my class?

Thank you for any help.

EDIT

So if I use:

Get  sftp> get spool01.1st to desktop/documents

Would that get the file back?

Comment: @LuisRamos Judging by your attempt to edit your question as a new user you have accidentally created two accounts. You should use the [contact form](https://superuser.com/contact) and select "I need to merge accounts" to have your accounts merged. You'll then be able to comment on and edit this question.

Answer (score 2):

The output `Fetching /class/cm320a/12/spool01.1st to spool01.1st` means that the file was copied from `/class/cm320a/12/spool01.1st` on the server, to `spool01.1st` on your computer. Since the destination doesn't have any directory path, it is relative to the current directory – in other words, the file would be in the same directory that you ran `sftp` in.